# How to get the Group chat added member list from ChatBot in msteams

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

how  to collect all the group chat members from the chat bot using MSTeams?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GetPagedMembers capability for this - see the docs from Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet (switch to your language of choice in the samples blocks).

Note that, using this approach, you can only do this when the user is actually interacting with the bot (e.g. posting a message) because you need the context. If that's a problem let me know and I will send additional info.

Comment: i cannot use kind of api to get the member list ?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#get-conversation-members

Comment: Yes absolutely fine to do that - the document I linked to is simply calling that under the covers anyway. You just need to handle the authentication yourself, and have to have the conversation id.

Comment: But i don't want to use this information in bot section., have to bind in my popup section in react side is it possible then [please check this url](https://i.ibb.co/LYV1Q1B/search-user-binding.png)

Comment: yes, it's possible, but you need to -have- the conversation id. You can get it immediately when the user installs the bot, through the 'conversationUpdate' event. Then you can store it, like in a database, and use it whenever you want to. It's similar to what we do with something called 'proactive messaging'.

Comment: Is there is any specific method to get all chat members(who ever added in the chat)?@Hilton Giesenow

Comment: Yes, I think the one you linked to would be fine, or the 'pagedmembers' is safer even

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two ways that can work for you

1. Using graph - [List members of a chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Refer this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/24.bot-authentication-msgraph).
2. [Get conversation member.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#get-conversation-members) (you are already aware about this as I can see.)

Comment: i was getting 401 exception when i was trying with postman and i don't know where& how to get the access token.[postmanerror](i.ibb.co/mSJySRt/401-exception.png)(i.ibb.co/mSJySRt/401-exception.png) => postman error info

Comment: You need access token. Best way to check graph API call is [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).